# Appium can't run Xamarin Forms app that has SplashActivity

Tags: xamarin.forms, appium, uitest

Issue seem to happen with Xamarin Form app that has Splash Activity. Run fine on Xamarin Form app without Splash Activity

Error:

`my.company.package.crc647d31b46756051f61.SplashActivity' never started`

`ADB] Incorrect package and activity. Retrying.`

Answer (score 3):

I found that with Xamarin Forms app that has SplashActivity, we need to wait for wildcard `*.MainActivity`

Something like this:

`appiumOptions.AddAdditionalCapability("appWaitActivity", "*.MainActivity");`

More details at [Appium Android Capbilities docs](https://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/caps/)